# how to pass a Javascript array from Javascript to PHP through Jquery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I would like to know how I can pass a `Javascript` array from `Javascript` to `PHP` through `Jquery/Ajax`. In fact I created two files: `t1.html` and `moslem3.php` . The code of each file is below:

The code of t1.html:

```
 <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = ["actor", "subject", "object"];
        $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: 'moslem3.php',
        data: table 
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code of moslem3.php:

```
<?php
$myArray = $_REQUEST['table'];
echo $myArray;
?>
```

The file `moslem3.php` displays this message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: table in C:\wamp\www\test1\moslem3.php on line 2
```

So my question is: where is the wrong here exactly?..Is there any one who has any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `echo json_encode($myArray);`

Comment: Then in your ajax call add `success: function(result){ .... }`. BTW your ajax call need tweaking.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-0, data: { table: table }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = ["actor", "subject", "object"];
    $.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: 'moslem3.php',
    data: {t_name:table },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Change in moslem3.php**

```
<?php
    $myArray = $_REQUEST['t_name'];
    print_r($myArray);
?>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I did that but the file moslem3.php still display this message: Notice: Undefined index: table in C:\wamp\www\test1\moslem3.php on line 2

Comment: Carefully follow my given answer. In that answer i changed the index table to t_name.

Comment: yes, I follow your answer exactly, the file t1.html displays exactly what it is in you screenshot above, but the file moslem3.php still displays that message.

Comment: just check data: {t_name:table } and $myArray = $_REQUEST['t_name'].

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't inherently know anything about the JavaScript variables being used, such as `var table`. Its insights for the `$.ajax()` request are completed limited to the `data` structure.

So, for PHP to know about a `'table'` parameter in `$_REQUEST`, the `data` needs to include it that as a named value:

```
data: { table: table }
```

This defines the `data` as an `Object` with a property `table` assigned to the value of the variable by the same name.

---

You can witness the difference using [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), which `$.ajax()` uses:

```
var table = ["actor", "subject", "object"];

console.log($.param(table));
// "undefined=&undefined=&undefined="

console.log($.param({ table: table }));
// "table%5B%5D=actor&table%5B%5D=subject&table%5B%5D=object"
```

Comment: I did that but the file moslem3.php still display this message: Notice: Undefined index: table in C:\wamp\www\test1\moslem3.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: 'moslem3.php',
        cache:false, 
        async:true,
        global:false,
        data : {
        "table": table }
        }).done(function(msg) {
alert(msg);
})
```